# jquery html return php Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to jquery to return php value inside div I'm using .html() but I did get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**
my html code is :

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function()
            $('#post-msg-<?= $divId ?>').html(`<?= \humhub\actions\TextFormatAction::text_html($model->message) ?>`);
        });
    </script>
```

on inspect element I see my php code is :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#post-msg-e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd').html('<p></p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?file=d2dd907d-bfd4-40ab-832f-bd8c161fd60e+" alt="" title="" />
<p> 
            <div class="div-div">
                <div>
                    <div class="div-title-description">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="div-title">Title-text</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="div-description">Description - text </p>
                    </div>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
');
        });
```

Comment: `.html('<p></p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?file=d2dd907d-bfd4-40ab-832f-bd8c161fd60e+" alt="" title="" />` seems to be missing `');` at the end

Comment: @Bravo I did copy past to what I get `<p></p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?file=d2dd907d-bfd4-40ab-832f-bd8c161fd60e+" alt="" title="" />
<p> 
            <div class="div-div">
                <div>
                    <div class="div-title-description">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="div-title">Title-text</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="div-description">Description - text </p>
                    </div>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>`

Comment: @Bravo is what my php function return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way it should look like to work. You should have no line breaks in HTML from the `html` function.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#post-msg-e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd').html('<p></p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?file=d2dd907d-bfd4-40ab-832f-bd8c161fd60e+" alt="" title="" /><p><div class="div-div"><div><div class="div-title-description"> <h2> <span class="div-title">Title-text</span> </h2> <p class="div-description">Description - text </p>  </div> </div></div></p>');
        });
        
</script>
</body>
<div id="post-msg-e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd">

</div>
        </html>
```

Comment: I have a php function code inside html()

Comment: Yes,  remove the line breaks. What is so complicated? html(`<?= str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',\humhub\actions\TextFormatAction::text_html($model->message)) ?>`);